# Extract private key from self signed .jks file in java

Tags: java, keytool, self-signed

I have signed .jks file. Need to get private key from the .jks file. How can get?

```
keytool -exportcert -alias selfrest -keystore filename.jks -file file.cer
```

Did not get the result. please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot directly export private key using Java's keytool. You have to use other tools like `openssl` to do it.

First you have to convert your `jks` to `pkcs12` format, and then use openssl to export the private key, like shown [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3779/how-can-i-export-my-private-key-from-a-java-keytool-keystore) and [here](https://dzone.com/articles/extracting-a-private-key-from-java-keystore-jks).